# Setting up T4UHP drivers and Interfaces

Tags: networking, software-installation, drivers, kali-linux, make

I was wondering how to install Debain based OS (Kali Linux) on my T4UHP,
get it setup and running. I have had a lot of trouble with most of the tutorials and have decided to turn to fellow Linux user input. I have installed the drivers using:

```
apt install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms
```

but still there is no light on adapter nor can i see the interface. Typing in ifconfig brings no new interfaces, i have tried reinstalling and rebooting. I tried Hunter's fix which worked really well until compiling the data, It gave me

```
> make clean make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux'
> make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C
> /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-amd64/build M=/tmp/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
> clean make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux'
> make[2]: *** /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-amd64/build: No such file or
> directory.  Stop. make[2]: Leaving directory
> '/tmp/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux' Makefile:1605: recipe for target 'clean'
> failed make[1]: *** [clean] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory
> '/tmp/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux' Makefile.dkms:11: recipe for target
> 'src_install' failed make: *** [src_install] Error 2
```

The `uname -a`:

```
Linux Crow 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What are you having troubles with? Add a little more information on what you tried already and what failed.

Comment: GAD3R, kali is a debain distro...

Comment: @Benjamin In the recent update to the question you added a bit about `make` failing, but you forgot to include the actual error. That would be found a few lines further up in the `make` output.

Comment: @Benjamin Yes , kali-linux is based on debian , it is better to use the correct tag for it. What is the output of `uname -a` ?

Comment: Linux Crow 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Ok, can anybody recommend a fix to my Make Issue?

Comment: I want to start programming my air-suite automaton with python

Answer (score 1):

Install these drivers, they support the TPLink T4UHP.

```
 apt-get install dkms build-essential bc linux-headers-$(uname -r) ## Install some dependencies.
 cd /tmp
 git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
 cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
 make -f Makefile.dkms install
 reboot
```

Comment: Hey, i am having a problem which i assume is to do with headers

Comment: Makefile.dkms:11: recipe for target 'src_install' failed
make: *** [src_install] Error 2

Comment: @Benjamin Try installing the headers and then `make`.. I have updated the answer.